# Excel formula for author names conversion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

does anyone know how to write TWO excel formulas that would change (A) and (B) respectively into (C)? I have hundreds of rolls of author names like (A) and (B). There are different numbers of author names in each string.

```
(A) Smith, John; Green, Yennis; Black, Eva; Brown, Robyn
(B) J. Smith; Y. Green. Black; R. Brown
(C) Smith J, Green Y, Black E & Brown R

(A) Smith, John; Green, Yennis
(B) J. Smith; Y. Green
(C) Smith J & Green Y

(A) Smith, John
(B) J. Smith
(C) Smith J
```

Comment: Do you want the names for (C) separated by " & " or ", "? Also the data isn't consistent. "Green, Yennis" "Y. Yennes" to "Green, Y"

Comment: What have you tried? What version of Excel?  Mac or Windows?

Comment: @matts Sorry I've fixed the inconsistency. So they should all be separated by "," except for the last two which si separated by "&"

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I've tried something with the REPLACE function but nothing really worked, I'm using Excel 2016 on Windows

Comment: What would be your output?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this using formulas would be to split the data using the "Text to columns" on ";" delimiter. This will give 1 name per cell.

To convert "Smith, John" in cell A1 to "Smith J" you could use the formula

`LEFT(REPLACE(A1,FIND(",",A1),1,""), FIND(" ",A1,1) )`

To convert "J. Smith" in cell A1 to "Smith J" you could use the formula

`MID(A1,FIND(".",A1) + 1, LEN(A1)-FIND(".", A1)) & " " & LEFT(A1,1)`

Depending on how much the length varies, you could filter the data to remove empty cells and create formulas based on length.

`B2 & ", " & D2 & " & " & E2` for 3 names, assuming you inserted a column to apply formulas to the right of each name. Or replace the cell reference with formulas if you don't want to insert columns.